# A variation of matrix spiral pattern

Tags: c, algorithm

I find some very interesting task to do. You have to make a variation of spiral pattern, that will look  like this
[Example][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTGDL.png

I tried to do this in this way, but its not looking like my example:`

```
int row = 0, col = 0; 

int boundary = size - 1; 
int sizeLeft = size - 1; 
int flag = 1; 

// Variable to determine the movement 
// r = right, l = left, d = down, u = upper 
char move = 'r'; 

int matrix[size][size]; 

for (int i = 1; i < size * size + 1; i++) { 

    int count = 0;
    if(matrix[row][col+1] == 1){    count++;}
    if(matrix[row][col-1] == 1){    count++;}
    if(matrix[row+1][col] == 1){    count++;}
    if(matrix[row-1][col] == 1){    count++;}
    if(count > 2){ matrix[row][col] = 0; }
    else{ matrix[row][col] = 1; }

    switch (move) { 
        case 'r': 
            col += 1; 
            break; 
        case 'l': 
            col -= 1; 
            break; 
        case 'u': 
            row -= 1; 
            break; 
        case 'd': 
            row += 1; 
            break; 
    } 

    if (i == boundary) { 
        boundary += sizeLeft; 

        if (flag != 2) { 
            flag = 2; 
        } 
        else{ 
            flag = 1; 
            sizeLeft -= 1; 
        } 

        switch (move) { 
            case 'r': 
                move = 'd'; 
                break; 
            case 'd': 
                move = 'l'; 
                break; 
            case 'l': 
                move = 'u'; 
                break; 
            case 'u': 
                move = 'r'; 
                break; 
        } 
    } 
} `
```

Do you guys have any idea how it should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much simpler way of doing it. Except the first line of 1's, notice how after every time you fill a line of 1's the next time you fill a line in that direction it's two elements shorter in the opposite end. Basically, if you move five down, next time you move up it's going to be 3, and so on. This leads to the following code:

```
#define size1 9
#define size2 13
int matrix[size1][size2] = {0};
for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++) matrix[0][i] = 1;

int left = 0, up = 0, right = size2, down = size1;
while ((right > 2) && (down > 2)) {
    if (left == right) break;
    for (int i = up; i < down; i++)    matrix[i][right - 1] = 1;
    up += 2;
    if (up == down) break;
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) matrix[down - 1 ][i] = 1;
    right -= 2;
    if (left == right) break;
    for (int i = up; i < down; i++)    matrix[i][left]      = 1;
    down -= 2;
    if (up == down) break;
    for (int i = left; i < right; i++) matrix[up][i]        = 1;
    left += 2;
}
```